# Reports are printed without margins

Tags: axapta

Reports are printed without margins. With the margins of the printer the text appears cut off.

The same occurs for the pdf files (without margins).

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue - the reports printed out correctly (both on PDF & printed material) for some users, but not for others. 
The Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update for XP was installed - users are now able to view / print reports correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving enough information.

Is it standard or custom reports?

You can start by checking the following properties:
On the ReportDesign, is the fitToPage property set?
Is the Orientation of the report correct?
Are the margins set to something specific?

What papersize is your printer set to?